# how to automate ALTER TABLE ADD PARTITIONS with/without Glue Crawler

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have noticed that ADD PARTITIONS are much more effective since I deal with JSON data in s3. A crawler I have set up is taking too long to complete. When I am asking it to only "Crawl new folders only", it is not really adding the new partitions. I am also unticking the "Update all new and existing partitions with metadata from the table" option.

What I essentially need is to automate ADD PARTITIONS as new partitions are added (should happen in seconds). I cannot do this from the code base that pushes data to s3 as they are a different team responsible for only s3 data population. I don't want the automating job to go through each record / metadata and fix the records (taking ~40 minutes now).

Appreciate any help as I am new to Glue and Athena.

Answer (score 1):

`MSCK REPAIR TABLE table_name` is the [easiest way](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/msck-repair-table.html) to update new partitions to an existing table. You can send this query from various SDK such as boto3 for python:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('athena')
client.start_query_execution(QueryString='MSCK REPAIR TABLE table_name')
```

You can trigger this code within a Lambda with a trigger when adding new files to the S3 bucket, or using events-bus scheduled events.

Answer (score 1):

Using a for loop you can go through the partitions of a table to extract the total number of partitions to use. With that you can use the following code for a lambda for example

```
  import time
  import boto3

  DATABASE = "name_database"
  TABLE = "name_table"
  query_base = "ALTER TABLE "+name_database+"."+name_table+" ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION (dt = '2016-05-14', country = 'IN')"
  
  output='s3://aws-athena-query-results-example'

  def lambda_handler(event, context):
      query = query_base
      client = boto3.client('athena')

# Execution
  response = client.start_query_execution(
      QueryString=query,
      QueryExecutionContext={
        'Database': DATABASE
      },
      ResultConfiguration={
        'OutputLocation': output,
      }
  )
  return response
  return
```

Answer (score 1):

Since different teams are responsible to write the files to S3 folder, event driven architecture would be best solution to get the partition added automatically in less than few seconds. When a S3 files are added, an event is triggered which invoke the lambda. Lambda will receive S3 metadata as input, and using the metadata, get the folder name and execute the Athena ADD PARTITION or Glue CREATE PARTiTION. Using the event driven, ADD/CREATE partition is called only for new folders.

If 1000+ files are getting written to S3 folder by different teams, then 1000+ lambda will be invoked which is not a good solution. To solve this there are two options.

Option 1: Check with the team thats writing files to S3, whether they can dropped a 0 byte file with different extension like *.trg after they have done writing with data files. S3 can be configured to invoke lambda only for .trg files.

Option 2: S3 can be configured to push s3 events to SQS queue.Then have a lambda schedule every 5 or 10 minutes which reads the SQS queue messages in batches and get the list of distinct folders from those message and then execute the ADD/CREATE PARTITION.

MSCK REPAIR TABLE is a expensive operation as it recursively lists prefixes and objects in S3 and will take long time if there are more S3 prefixes or objects.